# Lifecon package

Tags: packages

Where can I obtain the lifecon.sty?

In http://maths.dur.ac.uk/stats/courses/AMII/lifecon.sty it is not found.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Comment: @ChrisS, close voters: No, that is not a duplicate. This question is about finding a specific package that is not on CTAN.

Comment: the answer given below is the first hit if you google `lifecon.sty` it really isn't hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

That package doesn't seem to be part of the major TeX distributions, but you can find a copy of it in the [lifecontingencies repository](https://github.com/spedygiorgio/lifecontingencies/blob/master/vignettes/lifecon.sty) on GitHub.